# Color for String, in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

i think is a simple question but i don t kwon who solve  this,
Is it possible to put this

```
String asterisk = '*';
```

in red?

i try, something like that

```
String asterisk = '*', 
style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.red,
                      );
```

but this just work in

```
const Text(
     "Registar",
     style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.black,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     fontSize: 40),
                ),
```

basically I need to put the * in front of the "text('register')" and I wanted the * to be red

```
String asterisk = '*', color: Colors.red;


const Text(
     "Registar *",
     style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.black,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     fontSize: 40),
                ),
```

Comment: Is this for flutter or dart?  You've tagged both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`RichText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) widget to provide multiple styles in `TextSpan` widgets:

```dart
RichText(
  text: const TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: '*', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Registar',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 40,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: If this is for dart, the OP needs an ansi colored text string, not a widget.

Comment: Correct; however, I must assume it is for Flutter since they are using a `Text` constructor that has all the same parameters as Flutter's `Text` constructor. And I believe they update the tags to include `flutter` (not sure if they were present previously).